# « Que voulais-tu dire par » ou « que voulais-tu dire avec » ?

Tags: prépositions, formulation, reformulation

> Que voulais-tu dire par cet émoji à la monture baissée et regardant au-dessus des verres?

> Que voulais-tu dire avec cet émoji à la monture baissée et regardant au-dessus des verres?

Réponse à la question.

Je voulais te rendre nerveux et susciter chez toi un sentiment de culpabilité pour remettre en cause et vérifier l’honnêteté de ta réponse.

N’hésitez pas à me donner une variante de la réponse.

Comment: La partie « peu sûr de ta réponse » est en suspens ; on ne sait pas très bien si le locuteur (« je ») voulais rendre son interlocuteur peu sûr de sa réponse ou si autrement le locuteur était peu sûr de la réponse de son interlocuteur. Il faudrait rendre cela bien clair.

Comment: Le locuteur, peu sûr  de la réponse de son interlocuteur, cherche à projeter sur ce dernier son propre sentiment afin de l’amener à se dévoiler dans l’éventualité où il dirait faux.

Comment: D'accord, mais il me semble que la syntaxe ne rend pas cela clair.

Comment: La cause (« peu sûr de ta réponse ») peut toujours être mentionnée, sauf, à mon avis,  de la façon dont elle l'était initialement. (Comme j'étais peu sûr de ta réponse, je voulais te … — ou Étant peu sûr de ta réponse, je voulais te …)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Que signifie cet émoji à la monture baissée et regardant au-dessus des
> verres?

En comprenant le sens de l'émoji en question, on comprend sans doute pourquoi on l'a employé. On peut aussi utiliser le participe présent :

Qu'est-ce que tu voulais dire en employant cet émoji...

Les prépositions [*avec*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avec) et [*par*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/par) peuvent toutes deux indiquer le moyen employé pour réaliser l'action ; évoquent-elles respectivement *en employant*/*par l'emploi de* ? Je ne sais pas. L'action est une tentative de [*dire*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/rdp-srch?lang=fra&srchtxt=dire&i=1&cur=1&nmbr=3&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0) ; peut-être que la préposition [*avec*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/rdp-srch?lang=fra&srchtxt=dire&i=1&cur=1&nmbr=3&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0) est plus typique pour le moyen ou la manière mais ce n'est pas déterminant pour moi et je trouve les deux formulations claires.

Réponse :

> Je voulais te rendre nerveux, te faire douter de ta réponse et te
> faire sentir coupable pour vérifier ton honnêteté.
> Je voulais évoquer la [suspicion](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/suspicion), le doute, et voir comment tu allais réagir ou ce que tu allais répondre.

Answer (score 2):

D'une part, *par cet emoji* signifie clairement *en utilisant cet emoji*, la préposition dénote le moyen.

D'autre part, dans *avec cet emoji*, *avec* a un emploi qui, il me semble, ne relève pas exactement du moyen, mais permet de commenter un comportement, une attitude.

> Qu'est-ce qui t'a pris avec (vs. *par) ton coup d'éclat ?
> Tu voulais insinuer quoi avec tes petites allusions ?

Or une forme d'acte possible est le choix d'un terme.

> Qu'est-ce que tu voulais dire avec (vs. #par) ton "je t'en prie" ?

Je dirais que *avec* est empreint d'une certaine ironie, comme dans :

> Il m'énerve avec son petit sourire !

Mais  il peut être utilisé dans un contexte positif:

> Il me fait craquer avec son sourire charmeur !

Un exemple canonique de la littérature se trouve chez Molière, dans le *Malade imaginaire*:

> "Que voulez-vous dire avec votre bon visage ? Monsieur l'a fort
> mauvais..."

Cet emploi de *avec* est peut-être à rapprocher de l'ablatif latin dit de "circonstance concomitante". Ainsi chez Tite-Live:

> Vicit ergo Hannibalem non populus Romanus […]
> sed senatus Carthaginiensis obtectratione atque invidia.
>
> "Ce qui vint à bout d’Hannibal, ce n’est pas le peuple romain, mais
> le Sénat de Carthage avec ses dénigrements et ses jalousies."

(Exemple tiré de Joffre 2018, "Pourquoi le passif ternaire ?")

Cela dit, rien ne prouve, dans l'exemple de Joffre, que le groupe à l'ablatif ne soit pas tout simplement un ablatif de moyen ou cause.

Answer (score 0):

Les phrases pour la question sont assez correctes, mis à part deux inexactitudes : on ne devine pas de quelle sorte de monture il s'agit avant la fin de la phrase et une émoji (image d'un visage) ne regarde pas, ce sont ses yeux qui   regardent.

> **émoji**  *Larousse* représentation graphique — *Robert* Petite image utilisée dans un message électronique

*Autres options*

- Qu'est-ce que tu cherchais à insinuer *au moyen de*  cet émoji à la monture de lunettes baissée et au regard au-dessus des verres?
- Qu'est-ce que tu voulais laisser entendre *en te servant de*  cet émoji à la monture de lunettes baissée et au regard au-dessus des verres?
- Qu'est-ce que tu voulais laisser entendre *en te servant de*  cet émoji  au regard par dessus les verres de ses lunettes?  (*peut-être pas si expressif que les versions « monture »*)

> Je voulais te rendre nerveux et susciter chez toi un sentiment de culpabilité pour remettre en cause et vérifier l’honnêteté de ta réponse.

« Pour » est acceptable, et l'honnêteté d'une réponse est une chose qui est vérifiable (assez souvent), mais remettre la réponse en cause plutôt que son honnêteté est un choix possible qui pourra être jugé préférable.

*Variante*

- Je voulais te rendre nerveux et susciter chez toi un sentiment de culpabilité dans le but de  remettre  ta réponse en cause et vérifier si elle est honnête.